# jQuery - Can I submit a form into a div without reloading the page?

Tags: jquery, coldfusion

I have a page that loads another page into a div:

```
$("#AmenitiesDiv").load("Amenities/AmenitiesAdd.cfm");
```

In this page is a form:

```
<form action="Amenities/AmenitiesAdd.cfm" method="post">
<input type="text" value="" name="NewAmenity" id="NewAmenity" size="50" maxlength="50"/>
<input type="submit" value="save new amenity" id="SaveNewAmenityButton" disabled="disabled" />
</form>
```

I want to submit this form without reloading the original page.

I know I could do this using an iframe, but can I do it using a div?

I am using ColdFusion 7 and jQuery.

Any ideas?

Comment: You know the possibility to send [forms in jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) via XHR?

Comment: also for extended functions there is form plugin http://jquery.malsup.com/form/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using $.post, $.get, or $.ajax in jQuery will allow you to send form data to a server-side page.

$.post example:

```
$('#form_id').live('submit', function(e)){
    //Prevent the form from submitting normally
    e.preventDefault();

    $.post('server_script.cfm',$(this).serialize(),function(msg){
        //alert the response from the server
        alert(msg);
    });
});
```

You'll have to give your form an ID and change #form_id in the code above. The `$(this).serialize()` will parse the data in the form and create a URL string with the data, then send it to the script.

Comment: Nitpick: You don't *have* to give the form an id, any proper selector will do.

Comment: Awesome! I will give this a try right now and let you know how it goes.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Wesley Yes any proper selector would do, so why not add an ID to be specific? "jQuery, get me the 5th form on this dynamic page" or "jQuery, get me specifically form ID='form_id'."

Comment: @iKnowKungFoo: For instance, I generate form validation script dynamically, which selects the form by its `action` attribute (by default). Just wanted to make sure readers know that it's not a *requirement* to use an `id` as implied in the post. OP seems fairly new to jQuery and won't benefit from misinformation.

Comment: @Wesley it may not be a requirement, but it's a Best Practice. :)